# Stop Youtube Video When Closing Multiple Bootstrap 3 Modal's

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, youtube, bootstrap-modal

I've tried several solutions found here and none seems to work for me. I have several modal calls on the same page, each with a youtube video, which keeps playing in the background after closing the modal. It only works great on Firefox. I then found this solution:

[How To: Stop a YouTube Video from Playing when Closing a Lightbox Modal](http://webdevstudios.com/2013/02/13/how-to-stop-a-youtube-video-from-playing-when-closing-a-lightbox-modal/#comment-28458)

```
// We're binding to the 'afterClose' event that facebox
// fires when closing a lightbox instance
jQuery(document).bind('afterClose.facebox', function() {
// target iframes with src attribute containing 'youtube'
// (within the facebox-generated .popup wrapper).
var vid = jQuery('.popup iframe[src*="youtube"]');
// if such an element exists
if ( vid.length > 0 ){
// get iframe's src attribute and cache it to a variable
var src = vid.attr('src');
// empty the iframe's src attribute
// (this will kill the video playing)
vid.attr('src', '');
// and restore the iframe src url, ready to be played
// again when the lightbox is displayed
vid.attr('src', src);
}
});
```

And I changed it to:

```
jQuery(document).bind('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
var vid = jQuery('#portfolioModal1 iframe[src*="youtube"]');
if ( vid.length > 0 ){
var src = vid.attr('src');
vid.attr('src', '');
vid.attr('src', src);
}
});
```

And if works great stopping video when closing Modal #1, now I have 8 more modal's on that page and don't know how to add their ID to the script. I tried `var vid = jQuery('#portfolioModal1, #portfolioModal2, #portfolioModal3, #portfolioModal4 iframe[src*="youtube"]');` but that obviously didn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

The following script will detect if the modal is hidden and stop the video as a result using the youtube player API.

```
$('.modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
player.stopVideo();
})
```

Comment: Hi eroedig, thanks for your reply. I found that same solution on another post and it didn't worked for me. Here's my website [link](http://www.iscreatividad.com/clientes/msl/). If you have the time please have a look to see if you could point what I'm doing wrong. BTW, the code I posted, was working but just with one modal.